# Next.JS Error > Config file /config/custom-environment-variables.js cannot be read

Tags: next.js

Not sure what could possibly the problem.  The error is coming out from the `.next` folder.  Any pointer even for debugging will be great.

[image]

Comment: did you find a solution?